# Display webview in CustomDilog in android

Tags: android, dialog, android-webview

This Class

```
    package com.example.foootnotes;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class compare extends Activity {
        WebView web1;
        WebView web2;
        Button btn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.compare);

            // String str1="<html>This first Html data</html>";
            String str2 = "<br /><br />Read the handouts please for tomorrow.<br /><br /><!--homework help homework"
                    + "help help with homework homework assignments elementary school high school middle school"
                    + "// --><font color='#60c000' size='4'><strong>Please!</strong></font>"
                    + "<img src='http://www.homeworknow.com/hwnow/upload/images/tn_star300.gif'  />";

            Intent i = getIntent();

            String str1 = i.getStringExtra("htmlrespones");

            web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webfirst);
            web2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.websecond);

            web1.loadDataWithBaseURL("", str1, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

            web2.loadDataWithBaseURL("", str2, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.compare);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    WebView web5 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                    WebView web6 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);

                    web5.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "This is first ", "text/html",
                            "UTF-8", "");
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(compare.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                    dialog.setTitle("Differences");
                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();
                }

            });

        }

    }
```

my custom .xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
    />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text=" Ok " />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:text="This is for first Html"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="This is for scond Html" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/webView1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am able to Display Textview But i want display data in web view in custom Dialog when i display it is in Textview it working Fine But i have display large data in Webview i cant display data in Textview so please tell how i display data in webview within Coustome dilog ..Please Help!

Comment: what error are you getting while loading data in webview?

Comment: you mean you want to display your webview inside an alert dialog?

Comment: yes Like we display Text same as it i want to display webview coz we have Print Long Html Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String str2 = "<br /><br />Read the handouts please for tomorrow.<br /><br /><!--homework help homework"
                    + "help help with homework homework assignments elementary school high school middle school"
                    + "// --><font color='#60c000' size='4'><strong>Please!</strong></font>"
                    + "<img src='http://www.homeworknow.com/hwnow/upload/images/tn_star300.gif'  />";

 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(compare.this);
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =     (LayoutInflater)compare.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.Your_layout, null);

                    dialog.setContentView(layout);  

                    dialog.setTitle("Differences");

                    Button dialogButton = (Button) layout
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

                    WebView web5 = (WebView) layout.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                          WebView web6 = (WebView) layout.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
                    web5.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    web5.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, str2, "text/html",
                            "UTF-8", null);

                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();
                }

            });
```

Your Xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/webView1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text=" Ok " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: LayoutInflater layoutInflater =     (LayoutInflater)_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  these 2 Line what i have to Put its coming Error

Comment: d.setContentView(layout);    what is this here Error coming and

Comment: @andrian please check there is 2 Error coming

Comment: d.setContentView(layout);    what is this here Error coming and

Comment: Webview display But data is not displaying

Comment: Thanx its displaying now

Comment: Perfect solution..!! Thanxs a lot. @Andrain